# Setting access rule in Yii for action with the same name from different controller?

Tags: php, yii

I searched over the internet and I found nothing. I centralized all of the access rule from all controller in the  main **Controller.php**  from **components**.
This is my code:

```
public function accessRules() {

        $controllers = array(' '); $actions = array('index');
        if (Yii::app()->user->getState("isAdmin") == true){ 
            array_push($controllers, 'controllerName','ModuleName/ControllerName');
            array_push($actions, 'create');
        }
        if (Yii::app()->user->getState('isNormalUser') == true){
            array_push($controllers, 'controllerName2');
        }
        if (Yii::app()->user->getState("isAdmin") == false && Yii::app()->user->getState("isNormalUser") == false){
            return array(
                array('deny', // deny all users
                    'users' => array('*'),
                ),
            );
        }else{ 
            $controllers = array_unique($controllers); //remove duplicates
            $actions = array_unique($actions);//remove duplicates
            return array(
                array('allow',
                    'controllers'=> $controllers,
                    'actions'    => $actions,
                ),
                array('deny', // deny all users
                    'users' => array('*'),
                ),
            );
        }
    }
```

My problem is: 
In my module if I have a controller(C1) with a function named f1 and another controller (C2) with the same function name f1 and i want to give access only to C1 with f1? How can I do that? I observed that i can make the difference between modules with the same controller name giving the format

> ModuleName/ModuleController
>   Is it  smth similar to actions ? Thx

Comment: Just a thought. If you want a centralized RBAC perhaps you can look at the [rights extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/)

Comment: Well, my example it works fine, except that case? How can i manage that specific case ? Thx for the suggestion, but I would like to keep my example I don't want to use any extensions :)

Comment: Can't you just overwrite the `accecRules()` function in `C1`?

Comment: I believe it's much better to have `accessRules` function inside every controller, not parent controller. This solution suggested by Yii in the documentation. If you have complex access control rules, you should use Right extension(as @topher said) or implement your own RBAC module.

Comment: If I overwrite it means that I will have access rule in each controller , I do not want that

Comment: I wonder if is there a way to solve this using expression access rule